Index out of range in transformer summarization
Welcome to AI exchangers — thanks for starting a new conversation!
I am building own summarization app using transformer huggingface. But I can’t run one line code. That is bellow part.
 summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model="facebook/bart-large-cnn")
 loader = PdfReader(pdf_file_path)
 text = """ """
 for page in loader.pages:
     text += page.extract_text()

-->summary = summarizer(text, min_length=130, max_length=50)
The error is
return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
IndexError: index out of range in self"
Please help me!!!

Programming issues are off-topic here. Anyway, without the stack trace, it's difficult to say where the issue occurs. You're just showing the last error not the full stack trace. Index out of range happens when you try to access a position in an array that does not exist. For example, a[-1]
